# Why is Econ mode making fuel consumption worse on my CR-V?

Tags: honda, crv

I have a 2017 Honda CR-V and the Econ button seems counter-intuitive.

It's early yet but here are the actual results through 3 tanks of gas (skipping the first tank because the dealer did some work the apparently required a lot of idling).

I got 27.4 mpg , 27.9 mpg on econ, then switched econ off and on the same roads and approximately the same temps got 33.4 mpg on the next.

I live in Pennsylvania and drive hilly roads. Would that make any difference since it needs the extra power to keep the revs reasonable? Just seems odd. Highway driving didn't make any difference on the fuel economy - it was still mid 27's in Econ mode.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  It's a little unclear what you are asking.  After the background information on the MPG, try to pull out a clear question that we can answer, and make it a new paragraph so it's easier to read.

Comment: what is unclear? i said on econ mode i got 27.65 mpg average and on econ off mode in simular conditions i was getting at the time 33+ mpg, and that seemed odd and could someone explain it. the person with the answer didn't seem to have a problem with it. so maybe you troll somewhere else. also since the temps have dropped mpg have fallen dramatically - without additional idleing.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR Econ mode isn't meant for cruising or hilly roads. It performs best in city traffic. Without more data on your driving habits it's hard to say why you are seeing higher MPG on your commute. We can speculate that the change in the throttle and CVT maps are what is causing the drop in MPG.

Some copy pasta from Honda.

> The control system for improved fuel economy in actual traffic aims at
> disseminating eco-driving. It consists of an effective control system,
> ambient illumination and instantaneous fuel consumption indicator. The
> effective control system is activated by operating the ECON switch to
> set the ECON ON mode. The PGM-FI system, the CVT control system, and
> the air conditioning system control fuel consumption, which reduces
> the worsening of fuel consumption due to the driver's driving style
> and tries to improve of fuel consumption. The ambient illumination and
> instantaneous fuel consumption display function activate the light in
> the gauge control module to indicate the current operation status in
> real time, which encourages the driver to save fuel consumption.
>
> This vehicle has an ECON ON mode specifically for controlling fuel economy
> improvements in actual traffic, in addition to the normal driving mode
> (ECON OFF mode). With the ECON ON mode, "effective control," in which
> fuel consumption is improved by the PGM-FI system, the CVT control
> system, and the air conditioning system, is performed. When the driver
> operates the ECON switch in ECON OFF mode, the signal is input in the
> gauge control module and the signal switching to the ECON ON mode is
> sent to the PCM and A/C control unit through the F-CAN and B-CAN from
> the gauge control module. According to this signal, each unit
> transitions to effective control. In this step, the PCM directs the
> signal to the gauge control module through the F-CAN so as to control
> the lighting of the ECON indicator. When the driver operates the ECON
> switch in the ECON ON mode (during effective control), the mode is
> changed from ECON ON to ECON OFF. In this step, the signal is sent in
> the same flow as when the mode is transitioning from ECON OFF to ECON
> ON, and each system that received the signal stops the effective
> control. In addition, the status of the ECON ON/OFF mode is stored in
> the gauge control module and this status will be kept when the vehicle
> is set to OFF (LOCK) mode.

I believe this should read, ECON ON in the first sentence.

> **Change of ETCS system control**
>
> The ECON OFF mode softens throttle valve control to reduce fuel
> consumption when the accelerator pedal is roughly depressed. Also,
> throttle opening becomes slow in comparison with the ECON OFF mode.
> However, if the accelerator pedal is depressed more than a certain
> level, control automatically becomes equivalent to the ECON OFF mode
> in order to ensure the acceleration.
>
> [image]
>
> **Transmission Control System**
>
> - Change in shift map allocation against accelerator full pedal    depression
> - Moderation of gear change responsiveness
>
> **Air Conditioning System**
>
> - Switching to the recirculation mode
> - Reduction in compressor operation frequency
> - Lower flow rate

Comment: Perhaps the convoluted explanation comes from the translation process : I saw an on/off switch with the translated instructions as “light on /  dark on”... :)

Comment: thank-you excellent info. i won't be running on econ mode as far as i can tell again don't see any benefit.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, ECON Mode improves fuel economy for that (large) group of people who habitually stomp the accelerator after every stop, only to slam on the breaks again 5 seconds later, am I alone in finding that hilarious?